# Derivative of the composition of two functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Background, this seems to work (This is manually transcribed from the program, beware of errors):

```
J1[f_, i_] := DifferenceDelta[f[i], i]^2
D[J1[f + t v, i], t]
```

> ```
> 2 (-v[i] + v[i+1]) (-(f + t v)[i] + (f + t v)[i+1])
> ```

What I would like to do is replace the `()^2` with a generic function `JJ`, and later specify

```
JJ[x_] := ...
```

Here's what happens with the generic `JJ`:

```
J2[f_, i_] := JJ[DifferenceDelta[f[i], i]]
D[J2[f + t v, i],t]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Why can't it return a derivative expression in terms of a generic derivative `JJ'`, and how could I modify my code to make it work?

Comment: I get `(-v[i] + v[1 + i]) Derivative[1][JJ][-(f + t v)[i] + (f + t v)[1 + i]]`, not `0`.  It may still not be what you want.  If you're getting `0`, then you might want to quit the kernel and try again.  Perhaps `v` has the value `0`.

Comment: I think the issue was caused by a typo in the original post (`tv` was used instead of `t v` in `D[J2[...]]`); and now, with Michael's edit, it is fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
JJ[x_] := x^2

J2[f_, i_] := JJ[ DifferenceDelta[ f[i], i]]

D[ J2[ f + t v, i], t]
```

> ```
> 2 (-v[i] + v[1 + i]) (-(f + t v)[i] + (f + t v)[1 + i])
> ```